# Use Text field inside ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have this peace of code in angularjs:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in benchmarGeographyObj">

            <div style="padding-right: 60px;float:left;">
                <input readonly style="width: 100%;" type="text" id="unik"  ng-value="item.BEN_BENCHMARK_GEOGRAPHY" />

            </div>
  </div>
```

The Problem when i try to add ng-model in the input text, the value of ng-value disappeared, how i can fix this proble please ?

Comment: what do you mean by that? Can you please rephrase the question.

Comment: the code above works good, but when i add ng-model="module.obj", the value of textfield dissapeared

Comment: it is working as expected as you are binding `module.obj` two way bounded value to input, it will not take value from `item. BEN_BENCHMARK_GEOGRAPHY `

Comment: how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: what exactly you need there? would you mind explaining the same?

Answer (score 0):

From the ngValue reference:

> It can also be used to achieve one-way binding of a given expression
>   to an input element such as an input[text] or a textarea, when that
>   element does not use ngModel.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

This means you have to use either ngModel or ngValue, but not both. They conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.benchmarGeographyObj = [{'BEN_BENCHMARK_GEOGRAPHY': 1},{'BEN_BENCHMARK_GEOGRAPHY': 2}];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.1"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in benchmarGeographyObj">

            <div style="padding-right: 60px;float:left;">
                <input readonly style="width: 100%;" type="text" id="unik"  ng-model="item.BEN_BENCHMARK_GEOGRAPHY" />

            </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```